# Prevent vim from exiting in case of error during autocommand

Tags: autocmd, sessions

I'd like to save my session before vim exits. Here's what I have so far:

```
function SaveSession()
    let l:new_session = trim(inputdialog("Enter new session name: ", v:this_session, -1))

    if l:new_session == -1
        return
    endif

    execute "mksession! " . l:new_session
endfunction

autocmd ExitPre * call SaveSession()
```

This usually works, but if `mksession` barfs vim exits without displaying the error and giving me a chance to react, causing me to lose my session.

According to `:help ExitPre`, it sounds like it's possible to prevent it from exiting:

```
ExitPre         When using `:quit`, `:wq` in a way it makes
                Vim exit, or using `:qall`, just after
                |QuitPre|.  Can be used to close any
                non-essential window.  Exiting may still be
                cancelled if there is a modified buffer that
                isn't automatically saved, use |VimLeavePre|
                for really exiting.
```

Is there an event I can raise or an exception I can throw? My only other idea is to create a new file with changes in it, but it feels hacky.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: My read on that help is that _you_ cannot prevent vim from exiting, but an unsaved modified buffer will.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with it a bit more and came up with this:

```
function SaveSession()
    let l:new_session = trim(inputdialog("Enter new session name: ", v:this_session, -1))

    if l:new_session == -1
        return
    endif

    while 1
        try
            execute "mksession! " . l:new_session
            return
        catch
            echohl ErrorMsg | echo "\n" . v:exception | echohl None
            let l:choice = confirm("Try again?", "&Yes\n&No", 2)

            if l:choice != 1
                return
            endif
        endtry
    endwhile
endfunction
```

It works, but I'd prefer to cancel the event if possible unless there's a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: What if you get rid of the loop and `return` in the `catch`?